# Apexcharts: Dealing with unperiodic x-values

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have a series of x-values being dates and y-values that I want to plot with Apexcharts. However, the dates do not have the same distance between each other. Apexcharts assigns them all the same interval although the data is not periodic. Is there any smart way to tackle this?
In the end the dates should be placed on the x-axis with an interval between them according to the number of days between two dates.

Comment: If you use in `xaxis` type `'numeric'` or `'datetime'` it should work just fine https://codepen.io/Gahzee/pen/ZEovyvO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the solution myself, posting this for future readers.
[Patryk Laszuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16537039/patryk-laszuk) gave an important hint in the comments:

- Using a series of the format [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...] works fine.
- Setting the y-values for `data:` and the x-values for `categories:` will distribute the x-values evenly over the x-axis without taking the time between values into account for spacing.